# Symfony 4 - When logout : Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 7899 of 17631 bytes

Tags: symfony, serialization, offset, logout

I just noticed something disturbing in my Symfony 4 project.

I log in to my account without problem. But strangely, as soon as I go on a certain page, then if just after I logout, I get this error:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 7899 of 17631 bytes

[image]

Here is my **User** entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields = {"email"},
 *  message = "Cette adresse email a déjà été utilisée."
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Adresse email de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email(message="Veuillez renseigner un email valide")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * Rôles de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * Mot de passe de l'utilisateur
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 4,
     *      minMessage = "Votre mot de passe doit contenir au moins {{limit}}",
     * )
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * Confirmation du mot de passe de l'utilisateur
     * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="password", message="Vous n'avez pas correctement confirmé votre mot de passe")
     */
    public $passwordConfirm;

    /**
     * Nom de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 1,
     *      max = 20,
     *      minMessage = "Votre nom doit contenir au moins {{limit}} caractère",
     *      maxMessage = "Votre nom ne peut pas contenir plus de {{limit}} caractères"
     * )
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * Prénom de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 1,
     *      max = 20,
     *      minMessage = "Votre prénom doit contenir au moins {{limit}} caractère",
     *      maxMessage = "Votre prénom ne peut pas contenir plus de {{limit}} caractères"
     * )
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * Slug de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * Absences de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Absence", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $absences;

    /**
     * Service de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\GroupeValidateurs", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $groupe;

    /**
     * Soldes des congés de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SoldeConges", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $soldeConges;

    /**
     * Feuille de congés de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\FeuilleConge", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $feuilleConge;

    /**
     * Avatar de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Avatar", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $avatar;

    /**
     * Profession de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable = true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $profession;

    /**
     * Date de demande de réinitialisation du mot de passe de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $passwordRequestedAt;

    /**
     * Token de réinitialisation du mot de passe de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * Ordres de mission de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrdreMission", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $ordreMissions;

    /**
     * Signature de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Signature", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $signature;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Validateur", mappedBy="validateur", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $validateurs;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AbsencesPrevision", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $absencesPrevisions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $hexColor;



    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $autoValidation = false;

    /**
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     "not (this.getAutovalidation() == true and this.getSuppleant() != null)",
     *     message="Vous devez choisir entre l'auto-validation et avoir un suppléant"
     * )
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="delegues")
     */
    private $suppleant;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="suppleant")
     */
    private $delegues;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $activeMails = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Entreprise", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $entreprise;
```

I looked on the internet, and I do not see anything that matches my problem. At no time do I ask to deserialize my entity in my code

UPDATE :

This is my **security.yaml** :

```
security:
  always_authenticate_before_granting: true

  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: auto

  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    in_database:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      anonymous: true

      provider: in_database

      form_login:
        login_path: account_login
        check_path: account_login
        default_target_path: home

      logout:
        path: account_logout
        target: account_login
      # activate different ways to authenticate
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
      # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
    - {path : /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - {path : /register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /requete, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/reset, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/chef-service, roles: ROLE_CHEF_SERVICE }
    - { path: ^/validateur, roles: [ROLE_VALIDATEUR, ROLE_SUPPLEANT] }
    - { path: ^/super-validateur, roles: ROLE_SUPER_VALIDATEUR }
    - { path: ^/rh, roles: ROLE_RH }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I realize that I have this error when I go on some pages too. And so I have to refresh the page, which will redirect me to the login page. I will connect, and this time it will bring me back on the right page and without error. But if I go back then, again that will make the mistake.

PS : Please, excuse me for the bad English, I'm French

Comment: Usually after login you will have a session which stores the user info and then checks it in later requests to see if you are already logged in. For this the object will be serialized in the session. From the top of my head I can only imagine this error happening, when you changed something in the entity code and then the serialized data from the session does not "fit" anymore. Can you maybe provide additional details, such as your `security.yaml`? By default sessions are stored in your `var/` folder, so you could check for the stored session to see if the data looks right

Comment: Okay I updated my first post with more information ! :)

Comment: up, I've still this problem :(

Comment: Do you have any listeners registered to `security.authentication.success`? Can you check `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher`